# Django i18n {% blocktrans %} query

Tags: django, internationalization, gettext

I have been reading through the django i18n translation documentation and I can't figure out the best way to translate a string that contains html.

For instance, the html below. How would I retain `<strong></strong>` in the blocktrans statement?

```
<p>This email is to acknowledge placement of order number <strong>{{ order.order_number }}</strong> on {{ order.date|date:"D d M Y" }} at {{ order.date|date:"H:i" }}.</p>
```

Can a string be constructed somehow?

```
{% blocktrans with '<strong>'+order.order_number+'</strong>' as order_number order.date|date:"H:i" as order_date %}  ???
```

Any help would be appreciated! =)

Thanks,
imanc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your date needs specific language-sensitive formatting, you could make both of those vars in the view code and then just pass them to the template, where a `with` would be doable